# MassTransit Consumer not consuming messages when doing Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, masstransit

I have my consumers and endpoints setup for dependency injection but my consumer isn't getting the messages from the message queue.

I just have 2 messages for the consumer in the queue but mass transit isn't getting them.

This is my main program where I set everything up.
The appSettings values are correct.

```cs
public class Program {

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            var executableLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(executableLocation));

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
                    var appSettings = new Configuration().GetConfig();
                    var achievementFactory = new AchievementFactory();
                    var client = new MongoClient(appSettings.ConnectionString);
                    var db = client.GetDatabase(appSettings.Database);
                    var mongoRepository = new MongoDBRepository(db);

                    services.AddSingleton(appSettings);
                    services.AddSingleton<IRepository>(mongoRepository);
                    services.AddSingleton<IAchievementFactory>(achievementFactory);

                    services.AddMassTransit(x => {
                        x.AddConsumer<AddAchievementConsumer>();
                        
                        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) => {

                            cfg.Host(appSettings.QueueUrl, settings => {
                                settings.Username(appSettings.QueueUsername);
                                settings.Password(appSettings.QueuePassword);
                            });

                            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(appSettings.AchievementQueue, ep =>
                                ep.ConfigureConsumers(context));
                            });
                    });
                });

    }
```

But my messages are just sitting in the queue and not getting consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking to the code, seems to me that you did not start the bus.

Try using `services.AddMassTransitHostedService();` after configuring MassTransit

source: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core

Comment: I have tried doing this thinking that's what was missing however I then got this error: on my recieveEndpoint. `System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'CreateReceiveEndpointContext' in type 'MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Configuration.RabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfiguration' from assembly 'MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport, Version=7.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=X' does not have an implementation.'`

Comment: Seems like a package version mismatch, make sure you have MassTransit.AspNetCore referenced, same version as the other MassTransit packages.

Comment: That worked. Good spot! Thanks. Needed to update the MassTransit Package to 7.20. Thank you both.