# injecting a service into a queue consumer using MassTransit

Tags: dependency-injection, rabbitmq, autofac, masstransit, .net-core-3.1

I have a consumer that is configured like follows

```
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumer <Consumers>();
        cfg.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfgss) =>
        {
            cfgss.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), hostss =>
            {
                hostss.Username("guest");
                hostss.Password("guest");
            });

            cfgss.ReceiveEndpoint("Queue_Name", configureEndpoint =>
            {
                //configureEndpoint.ConfigureConsumer<Consumers>(context);
                configureEndpoint.Consumer<Consumers>();
            });

            cfgss.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });
})
```

The services are created with Autofac on a ContainerBuilder and EventService is the service that should be injected into the consumer

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost => { configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
    {
        configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
    })
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
    {
        builder.RegisterType<EventService>().As<IService>();
}
```

And this is the consumer

```
public Consumers() { }
    
public Consumers(IService EventService)
{
    _eventsService = EventService;
}

public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Msg> context)
{
    _eventsService.ProcessInternal(context.Message);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Whenever the message is received, the empty constructor is called but the _eventsService is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this thread

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68010188/6545021)

Needed to add the consumer to the config and AddMassTransitHostedService

this is the final working configuration:

```
services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddConsumer<Consumers>();
    cfg.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfgss) =>
    {
        cfgss.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), hostss =>
        {
            hostss.Username("guest");
            hostss.Password("guest");
        });

        cfgss.ReceiveEndpoint("Queue_Name", configureEndpoint =>
        {
            configureEndpoint.ConfigureConsumer<Consumers>(context);
        });

        cfgss.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Comment: You must be on an outdated version of MassTransit if you need `AddMassTransitHostedService`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I downgraded to 7.3.1 to keep it the same version as Masstransit.AutoFac, AspNetCore as you recommended in some other threads

Comment: MassTransit.Gateway.SqlServer is likely referencing an older version of MassTransit.

Comment: I recreated the code in 8.1.3 having only these packages as per documentation  
MassTransit (8.1.3)  
MassTransit.RabbitMQ (8.1.3)  
MassTransit.Gateway.SqlServer (0.2.0)  
with the code that you suggested, but brought me to the original problem I had with 8.1.3, for which I downgraded to 7.3.1 and added all the other packages of same version  
Could not load type 'MassTransit.IPublishEndpoint' from assembly 'MassTransit, Version=8.1.3.0

This is the comment before Chris's answer. was trying to edit it and got deleted

Comment: I removed MassTransit.Gateway.SqlServer package from project and still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `ConfigureConsumer`:

```cs
cfgss.ReceiveEndpoint("Queue_Name", configureEndpoint =>
{
    configureEndpoint.ConfigureConsumer<Consumers>(context);
});
```

And remove the empty constructor entirely.

Comment: I have already tried that, having found your same recommendation in another thread. It is commented in the method the way I did it.
But doing so, the consumer does not fire, and the message stays in the queue without being consumed